# Changing or rearranging your directory files

Tags: terminal, directory

How do you change or re-arrange your directory so that they are organized and in order and where do you do this at?

Watched tutorial videos, CIL cheetsheet's. I also take it, that your supposed to do this in the terminal. I have a Ubuntu terminal WSL.

Comment: You can't change the order of files in a directory. You can use options to commands like `ls` to sort them when displaying. E.g. `ls -t` will list them ordered by time.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: I didn't  mean to put the javascript tag in there.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: So what your telling me, that the files are in the order that VS code puts them in and you can't change or re-arrange them.

Comment: The OS controls the order that files are physically in a directory. Programs like VS Code and `ls` typically display them in alphabetical order by default. It might have an option to show them in a different order.